# Moving a partitioned table across regions (from US to EU)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to move a partitioned table over from the US to the EU region but whenever I manage to do so, It doesn't partition the table on the correct column.

The current process that I'm taking is:

- Create a Storage bucket in the region that I want the partitioned table to be in
- Export the partitioned table over via CSV to the original bucket (within the old region)
- Transfer the table across buckets (from the original bucket to the new one)
- Create a new table using the CSV from the new bucket (auto-detect schema is on)

bq --location=eu load --autodetect --source_format=CSV table_test_set.test_table [project ID/test_table]

I expect that the column to be partitioned on the DATE column but instead it's partitioned on the column PARTITIONTIME

Also a note that I'm currently doing this with CLI commands. This will need to be redone multiple times and so having reusable code is a must.

Comment: is that the documented behaviour?  Partitioned tables use a meta-column _partitiontime that you can't edit?  When you import into an ingestion_time partitioned table then you can set the ingestion time back by a year but I didn't think that you have that much control (I've not had any luck when I have tried). Have you tried partition decorators ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I managed to find out the solution. By using "--time_partitioning_field [column name]" you are able to partition by a specific column. So the command would look like this:

bq --location=eu --schema [where your JSON schema file is] load --time_partitioning_field [column name] --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON table_test_set.test_table [project ID/test_table]

I also found that using JSON files to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

When I migrate data from 1 table to another one, I follow this process

- I extract the data to GCS (CSV or other format)
- I extract the schema to the source table with this command `bq show --schema <dataset>.<table>`
- I create via the GUI the destination table with the `edit as text` schema and I paste it. I define manually the partition field that I want to use from the schema;
- I load the data from GCS to the destination table.

This process has 2 advantages:

1. When you import a CSV format, you define the REAL type that you want. Remember, in schema autodetect, Bigquery look about 10 or 20 lines and deduce the schema. Often, string fields are set as INTEGER but the first line of my file doesn't contains letter, only numbers (in serial number for example)
2. You can define your partition fields properly

The process is quite easy to script. I use the GUI for creating destination table, but `bq` command lines are great for doing the same thing.